# Unclutch those pearls

Tags: wordplay, cipher, word-search

**Can you see the hidden gems in this string of pearls?**

[image: short_string]

**Here they are:**

[image: short_string_gems_revealed]

**Now, in the same way, can you find the pearls of wisdom in this longer string?**

[image: long_string]

**Text version:**

```
<< MEREGENTTOGOLDIODETONCOESOJOUNDAGISMSENDOWNTIMESTETHIONGOLYCOAUTODEMELONSTIFFERGOMESTEXTURPEARNIGENTICEDELAYINJUDASLOTSATTOFFHATETHRATYCOOMETSUNFEWERODIMBETADEJUXDPG >>
```

---

**Clarification:**

1. The longer string is composed of several quotations by famous-ish people.
2. The quotations are written clockwise around the string.
3. The letters of the quotations are interspersed amongst each other in some way with no intentional pattern.
4. Each pearl (letter) is used once and only once.  In other words, each pearl (letter) is used in one and only one quotation.

The gem example is just a demonstration.  Any patterns found within their letter placement is purely coincidental and has no bearing on solving the longer string.

Comment: First thought- this seems extremely difficult

Comment: So I've found a few potential answers but some of them use the same letters so they can't all be right... trying to narrow it down, can you confirm if rot13("rkcrpg gur harkcrpgrq") is one of them?

Comment: @SQLnoob — No, the fragment that you wrote in rot13() is not contained in any of the quotations that I used to construct the long string of pearls.

Comment: rot13(1. Ner nyy yrggref va gur ybatre fgevat hfrq va gur dhbgngvbaf? 2. Vf gurer pbafvfgrapl jvgu rnpu yrggre jura qrgrezvavat gur arkg yrggre bs gur jbeq be cuenfr (abg pbhagvat gur ynfg yrggre bs gur dhbgngvba)? Sbe rknzcyr, nf ybat nf "N" vf abg gur ynfg yrggre bs n dhbgngvba, vf gur arkg yrggre nyjnlf 5 fcnprf njnl (trareny pybpxjvfr qverpgvba)? V qba'g frr ubj obgu bs gubfr pbaqvgvbaf ner cbffvoyr ng gur fnzr gvzr.)

Comment: @MOehm and JLee — I have added clarification.  See above.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Perhaps one of the pearls of wisdom can offer advice about barking up a wrong tree.

Comment: @MOehm — You may find the quotations to be surprisingly relevant.  In any case, you guys came up with some amazingly clever interpretations.

Comment: Does clarification #3 imply that every pearl was shuffled into a random spot?

Comment: @LukasRotter — The letters of the quotations have been shuffled into each other but their order maintained.  For any given quotation, the letter order is maintained and travels clockwise around the string.  At any given pearl, there is no regular pattern to determine which quotation the next pearl comes from.  For example, with three quotations X, Y, and Z, it might be Y4-X7-X8-Z2-Y5-Z3-X9-Z4-Y6-Y7- etc., etc.  Here, I've done it with KING LUKAS ROTTER:
  <<GROUTKTEARSKILN>>  Write that around a loop and you should see what I mean.

Comment: rot13 (V qb frr fbzr jbeqf sbe gur fbyiref evtug abj gung pna yrnq gurz gb gur evtug qverpgvba-jbeqf yvxr qbbe, zntvp, crneyf, rgp. Gur k va gur fgevat zvtug or hfrq gb aneebj guvatf qbja nf jryy...)

Comment: I guess a heuristic could be that the letters of many words should still be close together if the whole thing contains enough quotations. So [here](https://pastebin.com/wMqBjdaf) are the top 200 results when you search as follows: For each pearl (index), find 7+ letter words which can be made with the least amount of minimum required jumps, then sort by jumps.

Comment: I've taken a different approach than @Lukas. I've run a dictionary of words against the pearls and tried to find them by allowing at most ten other pearls between letters. Then I have printed these words with the according gaps. For a hand-crafted dictionary of words (which I thought might occur in pearls of wisdom), I get [this](https://pastebin.com/r7EygdhX). My hope was that I could see possible intertwinings so that I could get a foot in the door. Ah, hope!

Comment: @MOehm — I think you might be on the right track.  Some gentle, unrevealing suggestions:  (1) Your well-gapped words have the same ragged appearance as the actual solution.  That's encouraging.  But why don't I see obvious words, like MEN, EGO, and GET in your results?  Because they're not in your hand-crafted dictionary?  (2) Please keep in mind that I had to break the loop somewhere just to present it, so MEREGENTTO... might actually start you in the middle of a quotation, or even in the middle of a word.  (3) Please don't forget that your 10-letter gap maximum is an arbitrarily-chosen cap.

Comment: (4) Why don't you start your search somewhere around the most unusual letters, like "J" or "X"?  That might reduce your initial search space a bit.  (5) After you have extracted a particular word, that leaves behind some pearls.  Why don't you then run your algorithm again in the area of those remaining pearls?  If you can't find any other word(s) in the area that can fit into or soak up those remaining pearls, then that branch of exploration can be pruned.

Comment: EGO? I hope the quotations aren't in Latin. The "dictionary" is just a list of 150 words I thought appropriate for pearls of wisdom. If I make the list longer (by using a real dictionary) or if I include words with bigger gaps, the output is too big. (The output does wrap, by the way.) The output is just a first step in trying to find a pattern. Pearl-diving in murky waters, if you will.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The quotes are:

> "Good judgment comes from experience and a lot of that comes from bad judgment"
>  "Life's tragedy is that we get old too soon and wise too late"
>  "Experience is something you don't get until just after you need it"
>  [image]

Method:

> Scrape quotes from a website until server blocks requests, find one of those quotes by computer, find the rest by hand (which is far easier with only ~100 letters left)

Comment: Well done. And a well-deserved, but hard-earned bounty, it seems.

Comment: Holy Toledo, Batman!!  I was wondering if someone would/could take such an approach.  And you did.  I would give you even more points if I could.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I was able to find

> **THE PEARLS OF WISDOM** (not counting the spaces, obviously)

in the longer string as follows:

> MEREGENTTOGOLDIODETONCOE **S** OJOUN **D** AGISMSEND **O** WNTI **M** ES **T** ET **H** IONGOLYCOAUTOD **E** MELONSTIFFERGOMESTEXTUR **PEAR** NIGENTICEDE **L** AYINJUDA **S** L **O** TSATTO **F**  FHATETHRATYCOOMETSUNFE **W** EROD **I** MBETADEJUXDPG

There are at least 3 different ways to find that same string within the longer string.

Comment: Hm. I don't think this is hidden "in the same way" as the gems. rot13(With the gems, the number of pearls to skip are always the same for each letter, for example: Take the next pearl after M and R, skip three after E, skipt four after A.)

Comment: @M Oehm That's a great observation that I didn't consider. Also, in the original example, all letters are used, so they will probably all be used here.

Comment: That, on the other hand, is a great observation *I* didn't consider. (And I'm apparently not very good at pasting the correct parts from my rot13 app.)

Comment: It is impressive that you took a literal interpretation of the instructions and actually managed to find it.  What are the chances??

Comment: I have added clarification.  See above.

Comment: @SlowMagic Thanks for the clarification, but it seems that the fact that there is no pattern makes this puzzle extremely difficult, as I first thought. The number of ways to divide up that many pearls might as well be infinity.

Comment: Interesting.  Sometimes a puzzle I think is going to be hard turns out to be easy.  And sometimes, a puzzle I think is going to be easy turns out to be hard.  Maybe this one is super hard?  I wonder if someone could solve it using a computer.

Comment: @SlowMagic Yeah I know it is very hard to judge puzzle difficulty. I face the same issue fairly often. With something this large, even using a computer, I wouldn't even know where to begin since there are so many possibilities for words and word combinations, and zero confirmation of correctness until the very end when no words/phrases can be made from the remaining letters. Maybe having a pattern restriction would help, but I think it would have to be very strict, like all letters in a quotation are grouped in 3s in the long string and each group is x letters apart, or something like that.